# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Do I need a constructor?

Tags: c#

OOP beginner here and my problem  is when i get to this event :

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar2.Increment(-25);
        splitContainer1.Panel1.Enabled = false;
        Thread.Sleep(2100);
        int preAttack = myCurrentOpponent.SetAttack();
        oppAttack = myCurrentOpponent.Attack(preAttack);
        progressBar1.Increment(oppAttack.dommage);
        textBox1.Text += myCurrentOpponent.Name + "Used " + oppAttack.AttackName;

    }
```

I get an error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Things you need to know *myCurrentOpponent* is an object chosen randomly in a collection of 3 monsters type. I'll use *Gollum* for this example wich is one of the 3 types. Gollum inherit from Monster and overrides *Name*, *Level*, *Health*, *PreAttack* and *SetAttack* from is base.

```
    public abstract class Monster
{
    public abstract string Name { get; }
    public abstract int Lv { get; }
    public abstract int Hp { get; }

    public abstract int SetAttack();
    public abstract Attack Attack(int x);


    public Monster()
    {
    }
}
```

Nothing in here is set because of this :

```
    public class Gollum : Monster
{
    Attack[] myAttack = new Attack[4];

    public override string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return "Gollum";
        }

    }

    public override int Hp
    {
        get
        {
            return 100;
        }
    }
    public override int Lv
    {
        get
        {
            return 3;
        }
    }

    public override int SetAttack()
    {

        Random randnum = new Random();


        int x = randnum.Next(5);

        myAttack[0].AttackName = "Charge";
        myAttack[0].dommage = -10;
        myAttack[1].AttackName = "Scratch";
        myAttack[1].dommage = -12;
        myAttack[2].AttackName = "Throw Rock";
        myAttack[2].dommage = -15;
        myAttack[3].AttackName = "Strangle";
        myAttack[3].dommage = -16;
        return x;
    }
    public override Attack Attack(int x)
    {
        return myAttack[x];
    }

    public Gollum()
    {
    }
```

Everything is set in the 3 monster sub-classes. Now, let's say the chosen monster is Gollum and I click button 1, as soon as the compiler reaches this line...

```
     myAttack[0].AttackName = "Charge";
```

... called from this line...

```
    int preAttack = myCurrentOpponent.SetAttack();
```

...I get the error.
Am i missing a constructor for my *Gollum Class* ? And if I am how can i code it
since everything is set directly in the property.
I really hope someone can help me on this on because I really don't know where to look.
Hope this is clear enough and don't hesitate to ask if you need more code lines.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't filled the arrat `myAttack` with any objects. When you initialize the array, it is created with `null` references. You need to add these lines before the line you get the error on:

```
myAttack[0]=new Attack();
myAttack[1]=new Attack();
myAttack[2]=new Attack();
myAttack[3]=new Attack();
```

This initializes each array entry with a new `Attack` object so that you can now set properties on them.

Comment: That did the job!
Kind of obvious now that I see it in front of me..
Thanks a lot flipchart!!

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to mark the an answer as accepted if it answered your question fully. See the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for info :)

Comment: I'm trying to but it says I have to wait a few minutes but i'll do it as soon as possible :)

Answer (score 3):

You declared your array at the top of the class

```
 Attack[] myAttack = new Attack[4];
```

But all this does is create an array with 4 slots, each filled by the default value for the type. For a class, that default would be null. You need to initialize those slots. For an array, it's typical to perhaps do this in a loop.

```
for (int index = 0; index < myAttack.Length; index++)
{
    myAttack[index] = new Attack();
}
```

Since your array's elements are not instantiated, you run into the `NullReferenceException` at runtime when you try to access an element's members.